# Promise not returning the intended file in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

```
function getJSON(url){
  return $http.get(url).success(function(response){

    var result = response['entries'][0];
    return result;

  });
};
```

I thought that $http returned promises, so I did the following:

```
getJSON(url).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
})
```

However, when I log the result, I don't get the JSON file I logged inside the timeout function, but instead I get a HTML response file. This is what I ended up with:

```
Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

Do you know why it does that and what I can do to get the JSON file I logged in the $timeout function instead?

Comment: Looks like you got back the response object. Does a `console.log` in the $timeout shed some light on the matter ?

Comment: PS: why do you need a `$timeout` there ?

Comment: to update the scope value (apply create some problems apparently). actually, let me update the code.

Comment: Well you shouldn't need `$timeout` or `scope.$apply`. Also try not to use success. Use .then instead

Comment: I think it has something to do with success, but can you tell me exactly what's the problem? and also can you tell me how to use .then instead of success without breaking my code?

Comment: actually, i used timeout because I am using a scope.variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your method to this:

```
function getJSON(url){
  return $http.get(url).then(function(response){

    var result = response.data['entries'][0];
    return result;

  });
};
```

PS: initially you had a `$timeout` in the question and things were different. In this case `.success` should actually work. The only problem is that you can't continue chaining promises after the `.success` call

Comment: are you sure about that? I am using 1.3 btw.

Comment: that success should actually work. pham said that success returned a promise on 1.4, but I am using 1.3, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: It returns a promise in 1.3 too, the only problem is that if you later want to add another `.then` to it, you won't get the value returned from the success function. It's meant as an end of promise chain kind of function, or it's just incorrectly implemented

Comment: hmm, do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `var result = response.data['entries'][0];`?

Comment: yeah, i changed success to then and I got a "property x of undefined" error

Comment: yeah, you are right georgeawg. thank you, it now works.

Comment: Cool. As I said in the other answer. `.success` is deprecated now. We all need to learn how to use `.then`.

Comment: @georgeawg can't argue with that.

Answer (score 0):

`$http` does return a promise. (EDITED I was make a mistake) And any of its child method will return a promise too.

Updated anser: Don't return anything inside your `success()` method. Neither for `error()` or `then()`

Try this it will return you a promise

```
function getJSON(url){
  return $http.get(url)
};

getJSON(url).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

P.S. in case you want to have business like you have made in your code. I will suggest you to use `$q`

```js
function getJSON(url){
  var d = $q.dever();
  $http.get(url).then(function (res){
     d.resolve(res['entries'][0])
  });
  return d.promise;
};

getJSON(url).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: how do you get the response if I don't use success? sorry, i am new to angular.

Comment: success does return a promise

Comment: Use `.then` instead of `.success`. BTW `.success` is now deprecated. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Before answer your question, I would like to know what is the angular version you are using. Later I will update answer with better suggestion. (and I maybe wrong because it seem like on version 1.4.x ```.success()``` does return a promise)

Comment: i am using an old version, 1.3

Comment: @sirrocco yes, my bad. It seem like the internal return of promise some how pass the value of response to the parent function.

Comment: Your last example is an anti-pattern, $http.get already returns a promise. You can simply: `.then(function(res){ return res.data['entries'][0]; })` . No usage of $q necessary