# Angularjs, do something when document loads

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am developing an angular js application, and i need to run a function, via service provider, before everything else. The function is a get request, which returns two variables in JSON, which returns either `true` or`false`.
If the variable is true, then load another state (i am using ui router). How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In angular the document loaded is not really has a good usage, because it is a framework and the we need to count on angular loaded/ready instead. Use `angular.module('yourApp').run()` like below:

```js
var app = angular.module('yourApp');

app.run(['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http){

    $http('http://localhost/status/').then(function(res){
        $rootScope.somethingStatus = res; // assuming that your response is either true of false.
    });

    $rootScope.$watch('somethingStatus', function(nv){
        // here is where you know your request has been done...
        if(nv === true) {
            // ...
        }
        else if(nv === false) {
            // ...
        }

    });
}]);
```

**NOTE**: please aware what run in `app.run()` will be fired before any controller initialing or view rendering. So later on when you want to access the value of what you been got. Inject `$rootScope` to the controller (or any place) when you needed it.

***EDIT***: fix some typos. Updated answer again, credit to @georgeawg and @Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant. Thanks you guys for the correction

Comment: The documentation for the run method -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run

Comment: Please fix you code. There are so many errors in it that it's not funny.

Comment: @georgeawg fixed . Sorry guys, it was a sleepy day XD

Comment: First problem -- Your closing square bracket is in the wrong place. Next problem -- $http returns a promise not a status. The result inside the `.then` should be put on the $rootScope. The httpPromise can go in a `var`.

Comment: Fixed the first problem, for the promise as I know it will always return a promise if using ```.success``` . But for ```.then``` you can directly return the value within the  return of ```.then``` . Check the correct answer for the question below. I just learn that recently.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771740/promise-not-returning-the-intended-file-in-angular-js/33771874

Comment: you should set $rootScope.somethingStatus = res; in the callback. like @georgeawg said. upvoted

Comment: Another thing, when the controller is loaded, the variable $rootScope.somethingStatus may be null. In that case, you need to use $scope.$watch('somethingStatus', function(previous, new_val) { }); in order to detect the change, and change the right state.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Done for callback return It was my bad, when not getting into the point correctly. About ```null``` case, it can be handled with operator ```=== true```  or ```=== false``` so it will save some performance of a ```$watch``` on ```$rootScope```.

Comment: What i mean with $watch is that you 'want the callback in which you change the location be called once the $rootScope.somethingStatus is changed'. You can't just do a test with `===`

Comment: Hrmm... yes, that make sense. I think I need to sleep XD

Answer (score 2):

You should write a controller for the page where you do the request (in order to display something to the user), with a default html view, and when you receive the response, then you change the state to use the desired controller.

Comment: I like your approach. If the request fails the user can get an error message. Also doing things in a `.run` block with $rootScope is hacky and has testability issues.

Comment: @georgeawg: It depends when we need to have the call. If you need the call to be done when you are in specific routes, you will put the $http call in the desired controllers. If you need the call to be executed in any page (for example retrieve the user information from the API, when you use Ctrl+R in any page) you should put it in the .run .

Comment: Can't retrieving user information be put in the routes resolver function? Resolver functions accept promises and route loading waits for those promises to resolve.

Comment: @georgeawg: never used it, I should look at. thx for the tip.